# Remove dynamic_cast in derived class of tree node

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I have a class which is a node of a tree, called Node. I need to create a DerivedNode class type which has some extra functionality. The problem is that Node has a vector of Node* as a member variable, so when DerivedNode inherits from Node, it inherits this vector. I've created a basic example showing the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Node {
public:
    Node(int value_) : value(value_) {}
    int foo() { return value; }
    virtual void add(Node* new_node) {
        children.push_back(new_node);
    }
protected:
    std::vector<Node*> children;
    int value;
};

class DerivedNode : public Node {
public:
    DerivedNode(int value_) : Node(value_) {}
    int bar() { return value*2; }
    // Ensures we only add children of type DynamicNode*
    virtual void add(DerivedNode* new_node) {
        children.push_back(new_node);
    }
    void print() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << dynamic_cast<DerivedNode*>(children[i])->bar() << std::endl;
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    DerivedNode* child_a = new DerivedNode(5);
    DerivedNode* child_b = new DerivedNode(6);
    DerivedNode parent(1);
    parent.add(child_a);
    parent.add(child_b);
    parent.print();
    delete child_a;
    delete child_b;
}
```

My question is, how can I do this without the `dynamic_cast`? My actual code is far more complex which means that there are dynamic casts everywhere.

Comment: I think `DerivedNode` children should be in a `std::vector<DerivedNode*>`, especially if you know before-hand that it will only contain `DerviedNode*`s.

Comment: Add virtual member function `bar()` in the base class?

Comment: @DragonRock I've tried that, it creates many problems much worse that a dynamic_cast. The issue is because there are two children, so methods in Node will call the vector<Node*> version and methods in DerivedNode will call vector<DerivedNode*> version

Comment: You seem to labor under assumption that all `Node` instances stored in `children` of a `DerivedNode` are themselves `DerivedNode`s. Be aware that your code does not actually maintain any such invariant - it's possible to write `parent.Node::add(new Node(42));`, or `Node& base=parent; base.add(new Node(42));`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, I don't think so. The `add` function is overloaded and virtual and only accepts `DynamicNode*`. A `Node` is not a `DynamicNode`

Comment: Your Node class is not suitable as a baseclass, it doesn't have a virtual destructor. Making add() virtual is useless, since the derived class only adds an overload, it doesn't override the baseclass' version. That said, using dynamic cast without checking the result is futile, use a static cast if you are sure. If you want to be sure, rather turn the Node class into a template.

Comment: @DragonRock Tried that too. I can't overload the `getChildren` method because the return type for `Node::getChildren` is `vector<Node*>` and the return type for `DerivedNode::getChildren` is `vector<DerivedNode*>`. `vector<Node*>` and `vector<DerivedNode*>` are not covariant so it doesn't compile

Comment: @texasflood Yeah, I realized that just after commenting...

Comment: Yes, despite your not thinking so. [Live demo](http://rextester.com/XUFQQ1747)

Comment: How about using templates. Something like `class DerivedNode : public Node<DerivedNode>`. Then your children vector can be `std::vector<T*>`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah OK, didn't think about that

Comment: @MohamadElghawi I will try that idea out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First add function in derived class is totally useless, it does not override add function from base class, it overloads it. In such way you still can add Node*'s to the derived class. To prevent this you should override add(Node*) as private.

If you does not like dynamic cast, you may use static cast instead
or
You may have virtual bar in base class that does not do anything
or
you can cast the vector itself (the whole thing) and assign to reference or pointer to std::vector DerivedNode*

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it both ways. You either have IS-A principle reflected in the design of your classess, or you don't. If DerivedNode is Node, than the vector of `Node`s should be indistinguishable from vector of `DerivedNode`s - and no casts are neccessary. If this can not be achieved, that you simply can not use vector of base pointers.

Any dynamic_cast in production code for me is a hard block for any review, as it clearly violates the basic design principles.